# How to remove the self-signed root from tomcat 6 server?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a geotrust extended validation SSL certificate. The server is tomcat 6.
I did the following things:

1 - Generate key store file

```
keytool -genkey -alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore -sigalg SHA256withRSA
```

2 - Generate CSR

```
keytool -certreq -alias -file -keystore -sigalg SHA256withRSA
```

3 - Import downloaded p7b file provided by Symantec against CSR and imported the certificate

```
keytool -import -alias -trustcacerts -file -keystore
```

Everything works fine but Symantec's SSL toolbox is showing following warning

### Recommendations: Root installed on the server. For best practices, remove the self-signed root from the server.

Any ideas how can I remove Root from Server to avoid this warning?

Comment: In step 3, you do not need to use trustcacerts on the certificate during import.

Comment: Exactly. That was your mistake, as @user has noted. Redo it without the `-trustcacerts` argument and the signed certififcate will replace your self-signed one. Make sure to use the same alias when importing the signed certificate that you used when creating the keypair and the CSR.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the root self signed certificate from tomcat, you need to remove it from your java installation. This action is performed via  the keytool binary exectuable that is found on the bin folder inside your java jdk installation.

The options you should use to delete a self signed certificate from tomcat are the following:

```
keytool -delete -noprompt -alias ${cert.alias} -keystore ${keystore.file} 
-storepass ${keystore.pass}
```

For example, to remove a self signed cert called tomcat that i had installed on my machine, I had to use the following:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool" -delete -noprompt -alias tomcat
```

More info at:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I found was [this article](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=548338) which basically says "Browsers will receive your paid-for cert also get your self-signed cert" and it's their job to figure it out.

IMHO, Symantic's product wasted my time on a wild-goose chase.  They also recommend remediating BEAST with RC4 (I assume), which is not recommended.  Browsers are remediating BEAST.

```
BEAST
The BEAST attack is not mitigated on this server.
Root installed on the server.
For best practices, remove the self-signed root from the server.
```

I'd recommend this service instead:  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Their remediation articles are very helpful.

[This](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html) was the article I used to setup nginx.  It needed one change to get an A+

Comment: That's not correct. I can't see the article, not being a member, but the server won't send both a self-signed and a CA-signed certificate. It will only send one, with its signer chain if any. There is only one server `Certificate` message in an SSL handshake, and it can only contain one certificate chain.

Comment: I don't agree or disagree.  Here's what was said: "In addition, All that certificate checker means that when performing the scan its reading that the server is radiating out the SSL certificate > the intermediates > and the Root. There is nothing wrong with this as the clients when making the SSL connection to that website or service are in charge of rationalizing out what it needs in terms of chain certificates to perform a trust Handshake in the SSL connection.

Comment: Certificate checkers Will only show and spout out what they are programed by design. Technically its fine to radiate out the root and include it in the chain depending on the servers system and in some cases it is required to have it on certain server systems."  -- The internet

Comment: I don't understand what these comments have to do with mine. You've quoted something inaccessible that says something about sending two certificates that is clearly wrong by reference to RFC 2246. What you're talking about now eludes me completely.

Comment: @EJP, How is ssllabs complaining about the extra root certificate if it's not being sent?  You may be right about RFC2246, but I think you're wrong about what's actually happening.  Also, you complained about the link so to be polite I pasted it here.